# Problem with loading a field from xml via xpath

Tags: xml, apache-spark, xpath, hive

There is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SINGLE_FORMAT>
....
<STATUS IsActing="1" Code="22" GroupName="Active">
....
</SINGLE_FORMAT>
```

When parsing in spark works for me, I use this construction:

```
Xpath_string(SINGLE_FORMAT/STATUS/@Code)
```

I get this error:`a pseudo attribute name is expected`

When I selectively try to parse several lines in a spark or in a hive, there will be no errors.

Comment: Xml:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SINGLE_FORMAT>

<Status IsActing="1" Code="24" Text="Active"/>

</SINGLE_FORMAT>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any more code. The currently shown xml is not valid

Answer (score 0):

I think there is probably an error somewhere else in your XML (which you've replaced with `...` in the example).

The fact that the error message mentions a "pseudo attribute" implies a processing-instruction, which is XML markup that starts with `<?` and ends with `?>`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction

Processing instructions have just two parts: a name at the start,  and then the remainder is just content. Often people will create what looks like a list of attributes as the processing instruction's content, but they are not part of the abstract data model of processing instructions, hence they get called "pseudo attributes".

Sometimes people can make a syntax error in the XML declaration at the start of their XML file. The XML declaration looks exactly a processing instruction (with the name `xml`) but it's not considered to be one. However your XML declaration looks fine.

I suggest looking through the rest of the XML file for processing instructions to see if one of them is the cause of your problem.

```
<?my-processing-instruction my-pseudo-attribute="foo" my-other-pseudo-attribute="bar"?>
```